# braintree Authorization Verify and store credit card php

Tags: php, braintree

I build eCommerce in PHP and this page should authorize the credit card.
If it is valid, I will store it on the customer page.

I wrote this code for it, but I still did not get how to authorize the card 
not to charge it.

**the code**

```
<?php
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST" && !empty($_POST['card_number']) && !empty($_POST['card_name']) && !empty($_POST['expiry_month']) && !empty($_POST['expiry_year']) && !empty($_POST['cvv']))
{
$card_number=str_replace("+","",$_POST['card_number']);  
$card_name=$_POST['card_number'];
$expiry_month=$_POST['expiry_month'];
$expiry_year=$_POST['expiry_year'];
$cvv=$_POST['cvv'];
$expirationDate=$expiry_month.'/'.$expiry_year;

require_once 'braintree/Braintree.php';
Braintree_Configuration::environment('production'); /* this is sandbox or production */
Braintree_Configuration::merchantId('id');
Braintree_Configuration::publicKey('public');
Braintree_Configuration::privateKey('secrit ');

$result = Braintree_Transaction::sale(array(
'amount' => 0,
'creditCard' => array(
'number' => $card_number,
'cardholderName' => $card_name,
'expirationDate' => $expirationDate,
'cvv' => $cvv
)
));

//echo "<pre>";
echo $result->message;
die;
if ($result->success) 
{
    //print_r("success!: " . $result->transaction->id);
    if($result->transaction->id)
    {
        $braintreeCode=$result->transaction->id;
        echo "<h2>Your payment successfully done ".$braintreeCode."</h2>";
    }
}else if ($result->transaction){
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($result->transaction);
        //echo '{"OrderStatus": [{"status":"2"}]}';

}else{

    echo "<h2>Your payment is not completed</h2>";
}

}
?>
```

Comment: share the error here. `paymentMethodToken` is missing in `sale()`

Comment: and from where u r using `payment_method_nonce`?

Comment: this thinks work good for payment put they need to authorize it verify it then store it in the customer page i didn't get example of it to work on it

Answer (score 4):

<sub>Full disclosure: I work at Braintree. If you have any further questions, feel free to contact
[support](https://support.braintreepayments.com/).</sub>

The easiest fix for what you are trying to do is to pass the [`storeInVault`](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/request/transaction/sale/php#options.store_in_vault) parameter into your `Transaction::sale()` call. This saves the customer information into your vault as long as the payment is successful.

Additionally, you can create a customer by integrating our [`Customer::create()`](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/request/customer/create/php) call into your code with the [`verifyCard`](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/request/customer/create/php#credit_card.options.verify_card) parameter.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend following the official guide at https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/transactions/php

The way you gather credit card data (such as number or expiry date) is not compliant with the requirements Braintree imposes and may lead to suspension or termination of your account.

Credit card data shall not be available to your server. You should rather use [Drop-in UI](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/drop-in/overview/javascript/v3) or [Hosted fields](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/hosted-fields/overview/javascript/v3).

Comment: i know that but the idea to verify it and store it